# How do we know if a new row is added in parse class

Tags: android, parse-platform

I a using parse as my backend . And i am iterating my activity every 10 sec. And as far as i know saving parseobjects in a list and using that to know if a new list is added to parse class or not . Now I want to do three things that is

- Show a notification and update recycler view(if new row is added)
- update recycler view (if a row gets deleted)
- update recycler view (if none of the above conditions happens)

I have created two ArrayList ie.

```
    private List<Rqst_G_S> list = new ArrayList<>();   // Parse List
    private List<Rqst_G_S> updatedList = new ArrayList<>();  //Local List
```

Below is what Iam doing

```
  if (updatedList.size() > list.size()) {
            recyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
            VR_Adapter load = new VR_Adapter(ViewRequests.this, list);
            LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(ViewRequests.this);
            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(load);
            updatedList = list;

            Log.i("sandeep123", String.valueOf(updatedList.size() + "1 " + list.size()));

        } else if (updatedList.size() < list.size()){
            Intent i = new Intent(ViewRequests.this, ViewRequests.class);
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(ViewRequests.this, (int) System.currentTimeMillis(), i, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

            NotificationCompat.Builder noti = null;
            noti = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext())
                    .setContentTitle("Requester Requested You")
                    .setContentText("From ")
                    .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText("From "))
                    .setAutoCancel(true)
                    // .setSound( Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.clean))
                    .setOnlyAlertOnce(true)
                    .setOngoing(false)
                    .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_MAX)
                    .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                    .setColor(Color.parseColor("#1ABC9C"))
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon);


            NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            assert noti != null;

            notificationManager.notify((int) SystemClock.currentThreadTimeMillis(), noti.build());
            recyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
            VR_Adapter load = new VR_Adapter(ViewRequests.this, list);
            LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(ViewRequests.this);
            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(load);
            updatedList = list;

            Log.i("sandeep1234", String.valueOf(updatedList.size() + "2 " + list.size()));
        }else {
            recyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
            VR_Adapter load = new VR_Adapter(ViewRequests.this, list);
            LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(ViewRequests.this);
            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(load);
            Log.i("sandeepabc", String.valueOf(updatedList.size() + "1 " + list.size()));
        }
```

When app is running first time then notification is shown but after that whenever parse list is greater than updated list notification is not shown .Any guesses what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is using very ambiguous language.
But i think you want to fetch updated list from Parse backend and update it on your UI? If so, the process would be as below.

1.When the activity is launched, start a `handler` that would keep posting
  a `runnable` to fetch list from backend. Use `handler.postDelayed()` to
  execute fetch after desired time.

2.After the updated list of objects is available, overwrite the dataset   you used to create `recylerview` with the new list and use notifyDatasetChanged() on your adapter.